# how to generate unique id based on time date month and year in iphone app development

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I want a unique `Test_id` based on current time, date, month and year for my quiz app on the basis of which I can calculate some other information.

Comment: Any reason you can't use the unique id objects provided by iOS? Namely [`NSUUID`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUUID_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (iOS6) and [`CFUUIDRef`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFUUIDRef/Reference/reference.html). Unique IDs are not as easy as concatenating year, month, date, hour, minute, second and millisecond. Especially not if you have thousands of users.

Comment: Here you are: `00018-ab6f-7209c4ed-14e3`

Comment: what the mean by unique id

Comment: Thanks matthias for your valuable support. you are rite but at my point there is only one user at time on his/her own device. Meanwhile i got the method.